# I want to cut the partial path from SVN URL

Tags: svn

I am a new bee in SVN...I want to cut the partial path(hdiits-traffic/src/com/tcs/sgvhod/trafficreports/) from the svn url. (svn://01hw538685:9001/HDIITS/Source/hdiits_mysql/hdiits-traffic/src/com/tcs/sgvhod/trafficreports/TrafficvioRepGen.java)

Comment: Please add more info about your task. What exactly do you understand as "cut the partial path"?

Comment: Can you set an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

For most command line options you can use `^/` to indicate repository root.

In your example:
Instead of : `svn://01hw538685:9001/HDIITS/Source/hdiits_mysql/hdiits-traffic/src/com/tcs/sgvhod/trafficreports/TrafficvioRepGen.java`
You can use: `^/HDIITS/Source/hdiits_mysql/hdiits-traffic/src/com/tcs/sgvhod/trafficreports/TrafficvioRepGen.java`